# Powershell Treeview filter is slow

Tags: powershell, winforms, treeview

[image]

*TLDR at the bottom*

I have a Treeview that filters folders. Previously we had figured out how to get the filters setup on this post: [Filter TreeView Nodes in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972019/filter-treeview-nodes-in-powershell)

However comma, I have found a new way to make the tool open a lot faster and pulls all 2000+ folders Instantly. The issue with the way found on the previous method is, it is only going into the Common, Licensed, and Restricted folders, which all of those have all of our software.

But when I need to go one folder deeper to look into the _non-cert, _archive, DesignTools, and Security tools folder, its also going 1 folder deeper on ALL other folders, causing massive load times, as its going from loading 2000 folders, to about 21000.

I have solved that issue, but now face an issue with trying to get it to filter info with those included folders smoothly and effectively like in the post mentioned above.

Folder Structure:

[image]

```
#Reset all Variables and cache
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps.AddScript('Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name') | Out-Null
$builtIn = $ps.Invoke()
$ps.Dispose()
$builtIn += "profile", "psISE", "psUnsupportedConsoleApplications" # keep some ISE-specific stuff
Remove-Variable (Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Where-Object { $builtIn -NotContains $_ })
#========================================================================================================
#build Form
    
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    
    
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Test"
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
        ($txt = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{
                Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(8, 8);
                Width    = $form.ClientSize.Width - 16;
                Anchor   = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]13
            }),
        ($tree = [System.Windows.Forms.TreeView] @{
                Location      = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(8, 40);
                Width         = $form.ClientSize.Width - 16;
                Anchor        = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]15
                Height        = 200;
                HideSelection = $false
            })
    ))
    
$approvedFolders = @('DesktopServices', 'Macintosh', 'Common', 'Licensed', 'Restricted', '_Non-Certified', 'SecurityTools', 'DesignTools', "$Filter")
$excludeFolders = @('Mobility', 'Server')
$baseFolder = '\\products\apps'
$FinalArray = @()
    
function Get-FolderStructure ($Path) {
    $baseFoldersList = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select -Property Name, FullName, Parent
    $returnArray = @()
    
    foreach ($folder in $baseFoldersList) {
        If ($excludeFolders -contains $folder.Name) { continue }
        $returnArray += $folder
        if ($approvedFolders -contains $folder.Name) {
            $returnArray += Get-FolderStructure -Path $folder.FullName
        }
    }
    return $returnArray
}
    
function Build-TreeView {
    <#
    foreach($arrayItem in $FinalArray) {
    if($arrayItem.Parent.Name -eq 'apps') {
    Create-Node -Name $arrayItem.name -Path $arrayItem.FullName -selectedNode $tree
    } else {
    $matchingNodes = $tree.Nodes.Find($arrayItem.Parent.Name,$true)
    Create-Node -Name $arrayItem.Name -Path $arrayItem.Fullname -selectedNode $matchingNodes[$matchingNodes.Count -1]
    }
    }#>
    
    foreach ($arrayItem in $FinalArray) {
        if ($arrayItem.Parent.Name -eq 'apps') {
    
            $approvedFolders | Foreach-Object {
                if ($arrayItem.Name -match $_) { Create-Node -Name $arrayItem.name -Path $arrayItem.FullName -selectedNode $tree }
            }
        }
        else {
            $matchingNodes = $tree.Nodes.Find($arrayItem.Parent.Name, $true)
    
            $approvedFolders | Foreach-Object {
                if ($arrayItem.Name -match $_) { Create-Node -Name $arrayItem.Name -Path $arrayItem.Fullname -selectedNode $matchingNodes[$matchingNodes.Count - 1] }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
function GetNodes([System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection] $nodes) {
    foreach ($n in $nodes) {
        $n
        GetNodes($n.Nodes)
    }
}
    
function Create-Node ($Name, $Path, $selectedNode) {
    $newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
    $newNode.Name = $Name
    $newNode.Text = $Name
    $newNode.Tag = $Path
    #$newNode.Add_Click({write-host $newNode.Tag})
    $selectedNode.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null
}
$FinalArray = Get-FolderStructure -path $baseFolder
Build-TreeView -arrayItem $arrayItem -selectedNode $null
    
#show Form
$tree.CollapseAll()
$txt.Add_TextChanged({
    param($sender, $e)
    
        $tree.Nodes.Clear()
        $filter = $txt.Text
        $approvedFolders = @('DesktopServices', 'Macintosh', 'Common', 'Licensed', 'Restricted', '_Non-Certified', 'SecurityTools', 'DesignTools', "$Filter")
        Build-TreeView
        $nodes = GetNodes($tree.Nodes)
    
        foreach ($node in $nodes) {
            if ($node.Text -match $filter) {
                $tree.SelectedNode = $node
                $node.EnsureVisible()
                break
            }
        }
    })
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

**TLDR:** Method found here: [Filter TreeView Nodes in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972019/filter-treeview-nodes-in-powershell)
Does not work as i need to include 1 more folder -depth for 4 specific folders and none of the rest.

again, this method currently work at loading all the folders, and filtering.. I am just wondering if I can have a way to make it not so slow at filtering, as it freezes the whole UI for about 3-5 seconds every keystroke.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . If I run your code, even by changing `$baseFolder`, I won't have a 21 000 items treeview so checking the performance and debugging is not really possible.  That being said, there is many things you can do to speed up your code. The easiest one is to replace any array building from `+=` to using collections (eg: list) and the associated methods (`.add`). `+=` force creation of  a new array each time it add an item. It is extremely inefficient.

Comment: something like this?
`[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list = @()
foreach ($value in 1..5) {
    $list.Add($value) > $null
}`

I will give this a shot, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Yes. This might speed up thing. The way you pipe things to $null might have an impact too, when looping 21k time ... I believe the fastest methods are : Ps5.1 `[void]$list.Add($value)` ... Ps6.0+ `$list.Add($value) | Out-Null`

Comment: yeah, just a heads up. I do have it filtering all the folders properly, so its not doing all 21000 items.. only about 2000, and it populates all the nodes damn near instantly (even on vpn lol). The only issue is when I type in the filter.. if I type "microsoft", it shows up like "m......... i.......... c........" like one letter ever few seconds. But after its done loading, all is well and it shows all the proper junk.

Playing with $list.Add stuff now, seeing what I can get out of it.

Comment: @SagePourpre getting the same kind of load times. I dont think the issue is the speed it reads the folders, but specifically how I am choosing to filter it. really appreciate the feed back however.

Comment: I think your issue is how your rebuild the tree each time. [BeginUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) / endupdate method can be useful too before you start rebuilding your tree and / or the use of addrange.

Comment: holy heck. how did i miss that.. its still a little slow but id say at least a 60% improvement on speed Just from that!

Comment: Another kind of optimization you can implement is a timer in the text changed. The idea is this. When the text change, a 100 ms timer is triggered. After 100ms, the tree rebuild. That being said, if the text change before the 100 ms is up, you reset it to 0. So if you type "Apple"  without timer, you have the tree rebuilt 5 times. If you have a 100ms timer/buffer and that you type relatively fast, the tree might be rebuilt only once or twice.

Comment: Also, if you keep a trimmed down version of the array based on the current filtering and rebuild the tree from it, this might reduce the rebuild time even more. For instance, you type "app" ... Then you have a tree of 10k items instead of 21k. If you type `l` and now have "appl", it would be logical to filter down from the 10k to whatever still match the new filter instead of building from the 21k result again (This hold true as long as you are adding letters to the filter).

Comment: yeah, i just swapped it to press enter to send the text and its damn near instant. which is dope knowing that I am so close to getting this thing working.